# Sony Spresense ハードフォルト　(ArduinoIDE)

Tags: spresense

spresenseを用いてハンドサイン認識の実装をしています。
以下のPPTの通りにすすめ、エラー無くスケッチの書き込みまで完了しましたが、LCDの画面に映るはずのカメラの映像が映らず、縦線が入ったままで白くて映りません。

(現在)シリアルポートを見てみると、Auto White Balanceの処理が終わらずにずっと真っ白な画面のままです。dnnrt.forward()から先の処理が行われない。spresenseボードマネージャーを1.1.2にしたところ、シリアルモニタにて以下のような出力になりました。

```
16:20:19.997 -> up_hardfault: PANIC!!! Hard fault: 40000000
16:20:19.997 -> up_assert: Assertion failed at file:armv7-m/up_hardfault.c line: 171 task: <pthread>
```

ハードフォルト。
ファイルでのアサーションに失敗しているようです。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54224121/troubleshooting-sony-spresense-hard-fault

よろしくお願いします。

PPT→https://github.com/takayoshi-k/algyan_spresense_ai_hands_on/releases/download/tmp_version/20190615_ALGYAN_SPRESENSSE_AI_HAnds_ON_at_.pdf
書き込んだスケッチ→https://github.com/takayoshi-k/algyan_spresense_ai_hands_on/releases/download/tmp_version/rps_sample.zip

現在のLCDとspresenseの接続状況です。[image: LCDとspresenseの結線状況]

[image: 真っ白でカメラの映像が出力されない。]

以下シリアルモニタの出力

```
16:20:17.391 -> USB Mass Storage start
16:20:18.981 -> Loading network model
16:20:18.981 -> Initialize DNNRT
16:20:19.692 -> Prepare camera
16:20:19.760 -> Start streaming
16:20:19.963 -> Set Auto white balance parameter
16:20:19.997 -> up_hardfault: PANIC!!! Hard fault: 40000000
16:20:19.997 -> up_assert: Assertion failed at file:armv7-m/up_hardfault.c line: 171 task: <pthread>
16:20:20.031 -> up_dumpstate: sp:     0d0439d4
16:20:20.031 -> up_dumpstate: IRQ stack:
16:20:20.031 -> up_dumpstate:   base: 0d043a00
16:20:20.031 -> up_dumpstate:   size: 00000800
16:20:20.031 -> up_dumpstate:   used: 00000128
16:20:20.031 -> up_stackdump: 0d0439c0: 0d0439d8 0d0254c1 00000000 0d0439d8 0d00c9e7 00000003 00000000 0d00c9ef
16:20:20.031 -> up_stackdump: 0d0439e0: 0d00c9cd 0d025af5 000000e0 0d0688bc 0d060060 0d04c0f0 0d068010 0d025a6d
16:20:20.031 -> up_dumpstate: sp:     0d068990
16:20:20.031 -> up_dumpstate: User stack:
16:20:20.064 -> up_dumpstate:   base: 0d068a48
16:20:20.064 -> up_dumpstate:   size: 000007fc
16:20:20.064 -> up_dumpstate:   used: 00000190
16:20:20.064 -> up_stackdump: 0d068980: 00000000 41800000 00000010 0d0134a1 0d0679e0 0d0679e0 0d060060 0d011fbd
16:20:20.064 -> up_stackdump: 0d0689a0: 0d068010 0d041dac 0d068a14 0d068a14 0d041e5a 0d003b2f 0d041a90 0d068a14
16:20:20.064 -> up_stackdump: 0d0689c0: 0d068a14 0d041e5a 0d002bc1 00000000 00000000 0d002c0b 0d045b80 0d006cad
16:20:20.099 -> up_stackdump: 0d0689e0: 00000000 000000e0 00000004 0d045d40 0d041e44 0d068a14 0d068a10 0d041e5a
16:20:20.099 -> up_stackdump: 0d068a00: 0d002bc1 00000000 00000000 0d004857 0d069090 0d0690a0 0d0680a0 0d068230
16:20:20.099 -> up_stackdump: 0d068a20: 0d049ca0 0d049cb8 00000000 0d006e3d 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
16:20:20.099 -> up_stackdump: 0d068a40: 00000000 00000000 deadbeef 674d7d87 e70272d2 c27bb529 00000190 80000810
16:20:20.099 -> up_registerdump: R0: 0d067ba4 0d05fc24 0d0679e0 0d0553f0 00000001 0d060060 0d04c0f0 0d068010
16:20:20.133 -> up_registerdump: R8: 0d002bc1 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 0d068990 0d0134a1 0d0553f0
16:20:20.133 -> up_registerdump: xPSR: 00000000 BASEPRI: 000000e0 CONTROL: 00000000
16:20:20.133 -> up_registerdump: EXC_RETURN: ffffffe9
16:20:20.133 -> up_taskdump: Idle Task: PID=0 Stack Used=0 of 0
16:20:20.133 -> up_taskdump: hpwork: PID=1 Stack Used=584 of 2028
16:20:20.133 -> up_taskdump: lpwork: PID=2 Stack Used=352 of 2028
16:20:20.168 -> up_taskdump: lpwork: PID=3 Stack Used=352 of 2028
16:20:20.168 -> up_taskdump: lpwork: PID=4 Stack Used=352 of 2028
16:20:20.168 -> up_taskdump: init: PID=5 Stack Used=960 of 8172
16:20:20.168 -> up_taskdump: cxd56_pm_task: PID=6 Stack Used=320 of 996
16:20:20.168 -> up_taskdump: <pthread>: PID=7 Stack Used=336 of 1020
16:20:20.168 -> up_taskdump: scsid: PID=8 Stack Used=320 of 2028
16:20:20.168 -> up_taskdump: <pthread>: PID=9 Stack Used=400 of 2044
16:20:20.202 -> up_taskdump: <pthread>: PID=10 Stack Used=480 of 1020
```

Answer (score 0):

拡張ボードのジャンパJP1(IO電圧切り替え)が5Vに設定されていませんか。
ILI9341のディスプレイは5Vには対応していないので、ジャンパは3.3Vにしておく必要があります。

写真がちょっと暗くて分かりませんでしたが、ハズしてたらすみません

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。指摘してくださった通り、５Vの設定になっていました。3.3Vに直しましたが、いまだ真っ白です。

Answer (score 0):

@Nmaru T さん

sdカードに"network.nnb"というnnb fileを保存していないと、
真っ白のままになってしまう様です。
※名前が違うとか。

自分はちょっとこれにハマりました。

Comment: ＠Chunさん自宅にて、SDカードの名前が間違っていないか、ファイル形式を間違っていないか確認しまして、間違っていませんでした。いまだ真っ白です。しかし、DNNRTに関する分を入力すると描画がされないことに気付きまして、そのあたりに問題があると思われます。

Comment: なるほど、そうなのですね。お力になれず残念です。

Comment: いえいえ、回答してくださったことに感謝します。

Comment: 私も同じ症状に陥ったことがあります。エラーメッセージも出なくて困ったのですが、その時は私の作った "network.nnb" の設計に問題があったようです。評価結果の統計（Evaluation:ConfusionMatrix）がうまく出ないことがあったのですが、そのネットワークだとうまく動かず、ニューラルネットを調整し評価結果の統計がきちんと出るものにしたら、うまく動きました。原因はいまだわからずですが、ニューラルネットの構造に問題があったのだろうと思います。今回の件の参考になるかどうかわかりませんが…。

Comment: Yoshino Taroさん　　コメントありがとうございます。NNCにてモデルの設計をされたと思いますが、評価結果の統計に関して評価がきちんとできたものはなんでしたか？モデルはPPTにて紹介されていたモデルを使用していて、そのモデルもConfusionMatrixを使用していました。　よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 私は Convolution Neural Network (LeNet) を簡略化したものを設計しました。MP3再生を追加したためメモリ不足となってしまい、LeNet を Conv 一段、Affine 一段にしました。考えてみれば当たり前なのかもしれませんが、最終段の Softmax への入力数がクラス数（出力数：私の場合は３クラス：OK, NG, 判定不能）と一致しないと評価結果がきちんと出ないようでした。うまくいくかどうかはわかりませんがご参考まで。

Comment: ご返答ありがとうございます。自分でもやってみます。参考にさせていただきます！誠にありがとうございまました！

Answer (score 0):

@Nmaru Tさん

こんにちは。

私もあるじゃんのハンズオンに参加できず、
同様に見様見真似でLCDディスプレイと接続してスケッチを試しました。

私も同様なハマりをしました。
その時は、
新しいSpresenseボードパッケージにしたときに、
bootloaderを再度書き込まなかったことが原因でした。

念のため、現在の最新v1.3.1にして、
bootloaderを書き込んで、試しましたが、
正しく動きました。

最新のv1.3.1で、bootloaderの書き込みをしてから、
inoの実行をしてみると良いかもしれません。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！カメラとマイコンをつなぐフラットケーブルの端子が少しめくれていたので新しいフラットケーブルを装着して、bootloaderを書き込んでinoを実行しましたが、LCDに映像は出力されませんでした。なにか初歩的な設定ができていないのかと思います。もう少し見直してみたいと思います。ありがとうございました。