# spresenseを用いてハンドサイン認識について

Tags: spresense, arduino, ニューラルネットワーク

spresenseを用いてハンドサインの認識を以下pptを参照して進めていたのですが
わからない点があります。

・ppt通りに進めたのですがLCDにカメラの映像が映らず真っ白のままです。
　シリアルモニターで内容を確認すると以下の状態で止まっています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
　同様な質問が以下URLにもあり、ver1.3.1にしたら動いたとあったので、
　やってみたのですが駄目でした。
  [Sony Spresense ハードフォルト　(ArduinoIDE)](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/56887/sony-spresense-%E3%83%8F%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%AB%E3%83%88-arduinoide)

・ニューラルネットの構造が添付のpptではわからず
　別のニューラルネットで出力したnnbファイルをSDに保存して使っているのですが
　下図のものだと問題があるのでしょうか？
　pptには28x28pixの画像データからグー、チョキ、パー、背景を0,1,2,3に分類しているので
　入力、出力に問題ないと思ったのですがわかりません。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ppt
https://github.com/takayoshi-k/algyan_spresense_ai_hands_on/releases/download/tmp_version/20190615_ALGYAN_SPRESENSSE_AI_HAnds_ON_at_.pdf

スケッチ
https://github.com/takayoshi-k/algyan_spresense_ai_hands_on/releases/download/tmp_version/rps_sample.zip

Comment: 正解かわらかないのでコメントにて。症状から察するに、IO電圧が5.0Vになっているのではないでしょうか？ili9341のLCDのIO電圧は3.3Vですので、拡張ボードのジャンパを3.3Vにセットしておく必要があります。私はそれに気が付かずにずっと5.0Vを印加しつづけてLCDが壊れてしまったことがあります。まさに画面が真っ白なままでした。（涙）経験上、正常なものはクロックが入ると画面がグレーになるようなので動いているなと分かります。

Comment: ご連絡ありがとうございます。
はじめ自分も気づかず、拡張ボードのジャンパを付け替えていなかったのですが、3.3Vに戻しても変化ありませんでした。
LCDは別のサンプルで動くのを確認したので、壊れてはいませんでした。

Comment: スケッチを見てみましたが、CamCB の中の drawBitmap まで到達していないようですね。可能性としては２つ。一つはDNNRTが暴走して forward から返ってこない。もう一つは、LCDライブラリが独自実装なので、そこで問題がおきているか。処理ごとにデバッグ出力してみて、どこまで処理が進んでいるか確認してみるとよいと思います。